# Как сделать возможность заходить в аккаунт на разных устройствах?

Tags: android, android-sdk, авторизация, регистрация

Делаю так

• Пользователь логиниться

• Выдаю ему токен и сохраняю в SharedPreferences

• При запуске программы в методе oncreate проверяю наличие токена в SP, если он есть то запускается окно профиля, если нету тогда окно входа

Так вот как мне нужно сделать чтобы можно было заходить с разных устройств под один аккаунт (так как если я зайду делая все по этой схеме токен для прошлого аккаунта перестанет действовать)?

Comment: если я все правильно понял, то это ограничение сервера, а не проблема в реализации клиента

Comment: Но все равно вопрос тот же,как сделать возможность заходить с разных устройств чтобы не выбивало прошлые входы?

Comment: На стороне клиента ничего не надо делать. Возвращайте один и тот же токен с сервера при логинке и будете работать как обычно

Comment: Окей а как тогда хранить токен?Если я буду хранить его в чистом виде то если утечет база данных это равносильно что пароли лежат в открытом ввиде так как используя токен можно будет получить доступ к аккаунту. Следовательно нужно хранить токен в виде хэша но если я буду хранить его в виде хэша то я не смогу возвращать клиентам один и тот же токен так как я просто его не буду знать

Comment: Вопрос не относится к Android, и хранить токены в шарах моветон, для этого есть AccountManager

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать так:

На сервере, в бд создать таблицу с девайсами. Поля:

- `id` (auto)
- `token` (токен)
- `device_id` (уникальный идентификатор устройства, полученный при логине с него же)
- `last_login` (время последнего входа с данного устройства)
- `user_id` (связь с таблицей пользователей)

На устройстве получить `device_id` можно следующим образом:

```
public static String getUniqueID(Context context) {

    //получаем IMEI
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String uniqueID = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

    if (uniqueID != null) {
        return uniqueID;
    }

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
        //если Android OS >=2.3 - то получаем уникальный серийный номер устройства
        uniqueID = android.os.Build.SERIAL;
    }

    if (uniqueID != null) {
        return uniqueID;
    }

    //получаем уникальный идентификатор Android (при сбросе системы может меняться)
    uniqueID = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    return uniqueID;
}
```

В запросах на сервер отправлять `token` и `device_id`. На сервере проверять соответствие.

Поле `last_login` необходимо для периодической чистки бд. К примеру если с этого устройства не заходили месяц (условное время) - удалять его.